# Read file with a su process

Tags: java, android, shell

Is there any other way than following to read a files content (NOT a text file, but an image file)?

I want to get a files `byte[]` or `InputStream`...

I can get following working:

- copy file to apps directory with root command
- read this copied file
- delete it again

This is slow and it needs the precondition, that there is enough space on the disc for the copied file...

Any alternative solution? Can I somehow read the data from a file with `cat` and create the `byte[]` data from it? Or any other ideas?

Comment: Regarding  _* copy file to apps directory with root command * read this copied file * delete it again"_, please add to your question relevant code.  Maybe its possible with a symlink?

Comment: What isn't working about `FileInputStream`?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: You can't run Java code in your app with root permissions.

Comment: @prom85: I never tried the variant using `cat` however this sounds to me like a working option. You only may run into problems to distinguish between the file content and other status/error output. It may be a good idea to develop a small tool via NDK that encapsulates the file content in some BEGIN/END structure that you can parse in your app when reading stdout of the su comand.

Comment: @robert I've seen an example with cat for text files which seems to work... I don't know how to use it with an image file though. I'm not sure, will the data that is returned from cat being the string representation of the files binary data? And I could convert them somehow? Creating a byte [] from it and using this for a bitmap? And I've never done anything with ndk yet...

Comment: @prom85 The result you get from an external process is by default an InputStream, therefore binary data may work. However you should not relay on a library/3rd party code that reads the data and returns it in form of a String.

Comment: Reading the `InputStream` via `cat` and trying to make an image from that does not work... I'm reading via a `Process` directly, no external library... Have you tried that already? I still can only cat the copy, read, delete method to work...